# How to remove anchor tags in image in wordpress plugin development?

Tags: php, anchor, wordpress

[Please click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7YbX.png)

In this image the black dot is another image on background image . I am able to embed that black dot on that post image.

```
    $embedCode ='div id="mainCHImage"style="position:relative;height:'.$heightOrg.'px;width:'.$widthOrg.'px;">'.   
            '<img style="background:none;border:none;height:'.$heightOrg.'px !important;width:'.$widthOrg.'px !important;"'. "src=\"{$matches[1]}\";>".'

            </div>

<img id="Icon" style="position:relative;left:'.$imgWidth.'px;top: '.$imgHeight.'px;padding-left: 10px;z-index:9999;cursor:pointer;background:none;border:none;" src="/Icon.png" onClick="showProducts(event,'."'{$matches[1]}'".')"></div>
```

This is code i am replacing for an image of post image in order to bring that black dot on that background image.
Now the problem is onclick of black dot i want to run a javascript function but in wordpress it is wrapped under anchor tag with href of background image and hence not getting the click event .But i have disabled the link on images then its working but its not the right way ..Below i m pasting the inspect element response of this code...

```
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/9.jpg">
  <img id="Icon" style="position:relative;left:130px;top: -30px;padding-left: 10px;z-index:9999;cursor:pointer;background:none;border:none;" 
src="/Icon.png" onclick="showProducts(event,'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/9.jpg')">
```

I m not getting where that anchor tag is coming from ..I have nt added in my code ..

Comment: how are you getting/fetching the image? are you just hard coding?

Comment: time being i am harcoding...

Comment: and your saying it auto prepends an anchor tag above the img tag? where's this code live?

Comment: Yeah ..U got it right...I have to tried and wrote in diff div but in vain..I think its wordpress property or something of tat sort..I m working on localhost ..so cant show u live ..

Answer (score 0):

```
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );

    function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {

            $content =preg_replace(array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}','{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),array('<img', '" />'),             $content);

        return $content;
    }


/*place this code in your functions.php*/


/*if you wanna remove anchor tags which has image links, follow below code*/
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );

function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
    global $post;
    $exceptional_cjtypes = array("Mashup");
    $cjtype = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, "cjtype");
    if(!in_array(strtolower($cjtype[0]->name), array_map('strtolower', $exceptional_cjtypes))) {
        $content =preg_replace(
                array('{<a href="(.*?(gif|jpeg|jpg|png))"><img}',
                    '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
                array('<img', '" />'),
                $content
            );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to place your comment inside of the Answer body. Its cleaner that way.